# mysql numeric calculation error

Tags: mysql

I keep getting this error :

> ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '81d119b1a5'

whenever i run this code in mysql

```
UPDATE myTable SET myCol = GREATEST((myCol - 10,000.00),0) WHERE myId = Id;
```

My table engine is innodb, CHARSET=utf8 and COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci. Also the data type for myCol is NUMERIC(10,2).

Can anyone please explain why this error keeps popping up. My guess is that i may have to cast to integers but its been unsuccessful so far.

**ADDEDUM**: Sorted this out by changing SET SQL_MODE = '';

Comment: the query has syntax error near `GREATEST(myCol - 10,000.00),0)`. All brackets are not at proper place.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it was a typo

Comment: `myCol` has `81d119b1a5` this value?

Comment: what was the `SQL_MODE` before?

Comment: sql mode was: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  UPDATE myTable SET myCol = GREATEST((myCol - 10,000.00),0) WHERE myId = Id;
```

this may work as there was some bracket mismatch.